# weborb and wcf service library with ado .net entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, ado.net, weborb

i've created a wcf service library with ado .net entity framework to handle the retrieving of data from the database and send it to the user.
i've been testing it in visual studio without any problems.
so, i moved the dll of the service and the xml configuration file to the bin folder of weborb, changed the web.config to add my service.

but when i invoke the service from the webconsole i get this error:

```
>The server was unable to process the request due to an internal 
>error. For more information about the error, either turn on 
>IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute 
>or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in 
>order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on 
>tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and 
>inspect the server trace logs"
```

can anyone give any help with this?
how can i get a working wcf service library using ado .net entity framework in weborb?

help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the WebORB log?

Then start off by trying the WebORB examples from [here](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/developer-den/technical-articles/flex4-wcf-integration.html).

The WebORB log should give you more detail about the error. With that info, I would post a question on the WebORB forum.